# CakePHP, is it possible to prefill forms?

Tags: forms, cakephp

I'm just wondering if its possible to prefill forms. I'm creating a website that requires users enter their data and others data before sending an invoice. I was wondering if its possible to code the invoice so that when a user clicks on the link to create invoice their username, is already on the form(meaning they only need to enter the data of the people receiving their invoice)

?

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->data['model_name']['field_name'] = 'Default Value';
```

Comment: Or better, if it is an existing record, something like this should load the entire record: `$this->set('customer', $this->Customer->read(null, $id));` in the controller

Comment: would 'default value' be something like 'username' ?

Comment: model keys are CamelCase, not underscored. Default value would be whatever you want pre-filled for that Model.field input